# How to handle relative positioning in iOS automatically?

Tags: ios, subview

I want to position a sub UIView (`sub_UIView`) as a subview of parent UIView (`parent_UIView`). When the `parent_UIView` resizing/moving, the `sub_UIView` would stay the relative position of the `parent_UIView`. For example, the `sub_UIView` is at the bottom right corner of the `parent_UIView`. When the `parent_UIView` is moving, the `sub_UIView` would stay at the bottom right corner of the `parent_UIView` automatically.

I managed to do this manually by updating the frame of the `sub_UIView` when the `parent_UIView`'s frame moving, but how to do this automatically in iOS? are there any properties for this? (similar to `autoresizingmask` for resizing subviews)

Comment: Why can't you set `autoresizingMask` appropriately on your child `UIView`? After all, it's a subview if you make it the child of another view!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I did this in the subview:

Comment: [self setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];

but seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

*Updated old response, that only mentioned resizing masks*

## Autolayout (iOS 6)

In iOS 6, autolayout was added, albeit, kinda ugly to work with XCode in a storyboard/xib. Autolayout is way too big to explain, but the essence of it, is that it's a set of rules between views within the hierarchy. Thus, you can stick the x position of a view to the right border of a parent view. See the [Auto Layout Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

## Autoresizing Masks (iOS 2)

Take a look at the options in the Size Inspector:

[image: Autoresizing and positioning inside a view]

This is the equivalent of doing

```
myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleTopMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleLeftMargin | 
    UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth | 
    UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleHeight;
```

Notice that there's a difference between doing it by code and doing it through IB. The IB autoresizing settings for the borders work as struts, selecting the right one, for example, means, "my right border is now stuck to the superview's right border".

On the other hand, code does the opposite, where you need to specify which borders are not strut-ed, aka. they are flexible. Height and Width works normally.

## Layout Subviews (iOS 2, but gotchas for iOS5+)

If everything fails, don't start doing manual positioning all over the place, I've been in that position, and it just leads to unmaintanable, spaghetti code, where three or more methods are messing with the same view properties.

Instead, prefer to do all your custom positioning on `UIView -layoutSubviews`. This method gets called as needed when a `setNeedsLayout` has been triggered, for example, when the width a view changes, the subviews get the layout subviews event. Also makes implementing rotating interfaces much easier, since this method gets called for the new width, to determine how the animation will look like.

Keep in mind that layout subviews works after Auto Layout/Auto-resizing masks have been performed.